# How do I get a dynamic form to update Text in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a form that is built with a wordpress plugin called Gravity forms.

I am trying to have the name when it is added be added to the HTML:

```
Hello [name]
```

Where "Hello [name]" is in the HTML (not in the form)

and where [name] is replaced by the input text field that I want it to be?

I created the form and found out that the field name is: input_1
and the id of the field is input_32_1

I tried this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#input_32_1").keyup(function() {
document.getElementById("fname").innerHMTL = document.getElementsByName('input_1')[0].value;
});
});
</script>
```

But it is not working.
Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML too?

Comment: are you talking about this HTML:

`<span id='nameFromInput'><script language="JavaScript">
document.write(document.getElementsByName('input_1')[0].value);</script></span>`

Where I have it put the name in the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup should be:

```
Hello <span id="nameFromInput"></span>
```

And script would then be:

```
$("#input_32_1").keyup(function() {
    $("span#nameFromInput").text($("#input_32_1").val());
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with it working as above:
http://jsfiddle.net/cTq7K/

Comment: I tried it nothing worked.  I am going to put a comment below, as I just typed it all out, and it said it was too many characters.

Comment: I tried that and a lot of variations of it:

`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#input_32_1").keyup(function() {
$("#input_32_1").keyup(function() {
    $("span#nameFromInput").text($("#input_32_1").val());
});
});
});
</script>`

and 

`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#input_32_1").keyup(function() {
document.getElementById('nameFromInput').innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('input_1')[0].value;
});
});
</script>`

ran out of room for the rest, so adding it in the next comment.

Comment: and I tried many others, while the HTML is like this:
`<span id='nameFromInput'><script language="JavaScript">
document.write(document.getElementsByName('input_1')[0].value);</script></span>`
and tried it like this:
`<span id='nameFromInput'></span>`

none of them worked. The only thing that works is this one:

`<span id='nameFromInput'><script language="JavaScript">
document.write(document.getElementsByName('input_1')[0].value);</script></span>`

Because (Ran out of room again, so going to add a new comment, yet again...

Comment: the reason that last thing works and the only reason is that Gravity forms knows I entered a Full Name, when I hit refresh the put it back in there what I typed before I hit refresh, so then when I hit refresh I see the current value in the HTML, but when I type a different name, it does not get updated.

Comment: Ok, I see that it works in jsfiddle, but it is still not working on my page. :( crazy.

is there a way to make it with every click on the page or key up or anything, that it will just update that with the input_1 field?

Like if they click anywhere on the page, scroll up or down, tab from field to field, type in any field, hit submit, anything?

Comment: Ok. I fixed it by paging the form.

I have them click a button to continue filling out the form, the HTML now pulls the data they submitted and puts their name on the page.

so that did it.
I don't know why it did not work before, there must have been a conflict elsewhere.

Thank you for your help. :)

Richard

Comment: No problem, glad you're sorted.