# How to dynamically replace part of a string with an input's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form on the left side of the page, and on the right is some plain text. In the form, there is an input. When a user types in the input, part of the plain text needs to be replaced with the input value.  So, for my HTML I have -

```
<form>
<label>Add your custom text</label>
<input type="text">
</form>
I go to libraries. <!-- "libraries" is to be replaced with the input value automatically without page refresh -->
```

I don't have a clue on where to start with JavaScript. Both JQuery and plain JavaScript answers are welcome. I might prefer JavaScript since I'd like to learn more about it. Basically I'm trying to build an html generator.

Edit - So the gist is, when a user types text into an input, how can I use that value to replace part of a string already on the page? Ideally, the update would be automatic and would not require a form submission.

I found an answer here that is close to what I'm looking to do -[How do I get a dynamic form to update Text in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864208/how-do-i-get-a-dynamic-form-to-update-text-in-html)

The difference is that I'm trying to find a string on the page and change it rather than finding an element and adding an inner string.

Comment: Try first, ask questions when you don't find the answer already here

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Try to reword it so people of SO can actually help.

Comment: @13ruce1337  Well, I did try but I didn't get anywhere whatsoever.

Comment: @sueanna I understand, but this isn't a place for tutorials. There is a multitude of info out there. This place is a question and answer forum. As taesu said, your question is unclear, and that is because you have no definitive question.

Comment: @sueanna post your attempt of doing this.  If you do i'm sure more people will be willing to help. At this moment in time this post have been viewed 35 times and i'm betting this is because you haven't show any attempt at doing this yourself. This isn't a site for developers to do things at your request. You pay a developer to do that, here you get help with the source code you give.

Comment: I see your update, not much of an update but to find a string you can use .indexOf("The String"); and to replace it you can use replace("The string", "replacement"); If you don't understand this then i suggest you display more an example of what you want so we have something to work with. We don't have time to make assumptions, we go by what you give. Give us nothing you get nothing.

Comment: That is basically what I was asking - how to get a string and change it. s

Comment: I successfully clarified myself from the looks of your comment, and I don't see how adding all the trial and error JS/JQuery that I eventually threw away contributes to the conversation. It would just bore you. Believe me, I try to learn on my own before coming here. Thanks for your code suggestion. I will integrate it with my previous attempts from today and try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you want to be able to add and remove a CSS class dynamically from a user input field.  If that's right then you can do that with jQuery like this:

```
// add class
$('.popup').addClass($('input[type=text]').val());

// remove class
$('.popup').removeClass('subscriptions');
```

That said you'll need to drive that code with an event, you can do that by adding a button to the page and calling the above code when that button is clicked.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
var tag = $($('code').html()).addClass('subscriptions')[0];
$('code').html(tag);
```

Comment: I don't think I can use .popup in this way because the div with the class popup is not parsed as html in my page. It's in code tags and is parsed as a string. When a user types in the input, I'd like for the class (a string) to be replaced with the input value.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will do the following:

1. check if you have filled up the inputbox
2. if you have, use the value of the inputbox and update the popup class

This is the farthest I can help with limited and unclear question.

```js
$('input#thebox').keypress(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if(e.which == 13 && $(this).val().length > 0) {
        var c = 'popup '+$(this).val();
        $('div.popup').removeClass().addClass(c).text(c);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='thebox'>
<div class="popup">popup div</div>
```

Comment: Some people need to help themselves before others can. As you pointed out limited information but still no attempts.

Comment: Excuse you, but I spent over an hour trying to research this and figure it out on my own. I'm not going to paste every effort I made here to prove that I'm worthy of anyone's time and help.

Comment: @taesu, What you're not understanding is that I can't use div.popup to manipulate its class. When HTML markup is in code tags, it's parsed as plain text -- a literal string in a browser window, if you will. Therefore I can't grab it as an element as you have in $('div.popup').removeClass().addClass(c).text(c);  If you look at my HTML above again, the div is in code tags. See http://jsfiddle.net/bohdoqLf/  My only mistake is that I didn't replace < with &lt; in my markup above. If that caused the confusion, my apologies. Thanks all the same. btw, my above comment is for the other guy, not you.

Comment: I still do not have a clear idea what you are up to, but okay.